# select field validation not working

Tags: jquery

I have a form with select field. I have problem with select field which is not validated with the following code. I have tried many solution given in stackoverflow but they are not working.
can anybody help me

```
<select class="form-control required"  name="package" data-style="btn-zmyhome" data-width="100%">
    <option class="col-xs-12" value="0" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select</option>
    <option class="col-xs-12" value="1">A</option>
    <option class="col-xs-12" value="2">B</option>
</select>
```

```js
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        package: { required: true }
    },
    messages: {
        package: 'please select'
    }
});
```

Comment: Your JS code is missing a `}`. Always check the console when something JS-related isn't working as you expect

Comment: Did you include the validation package?? `<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>`

Comment: yes i have included it

Comment: You should include validation library after `jquery`. As per @RoryMcCrossan what is console shows?

Comment: yes i have other textfield validation working. my problem is only with select field\

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing bracket `}` pointed out below:

```
$("#form").validate({
 rules: {
    package: { required: true }
 },
 messages: {
    package: 'please select'
 } /* Closing bracket `}` was missing here */
});
```

Comment: :) i forgot to put ")"  here only

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</head>
<form id="form">

<select class="form-control required"  name="package" data-style="btn-zmyhome" data-width="100%">
    <option class="col-xs-12" value="0" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select</option>
    <option class="col-xs-12" value="1">A</option>
    <option class="col-xs-12" value="2">B</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</html>


<script type="text/javascript">
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        package: { required: true }
    },
    messages: {
        package: 'please select'
    }
});
</script>
```

Please provide console log or share complete code.

Thanks,